# Restricting allowed app signers

Tags: android, access-control, code-signing

Android requires apps to be signed and since Nougat the signature acctualy guards all the parts of the APK file.
However it seems that anyone can sign their app, and verifing the signature would resolve correctly... even if I don't trust the developer.

Is it possible to set a whitelist of app signers/developers so only apps signed by them are allowed to be installed? (or vice versa with a blacklist?)

Comment: Are you looking to build your own Android firmware that has this restriction?

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm more interested in setting a closed developers community. Does such a feature requires that it'll be "embedded" in the firmware?